# Installing mini split system without wall core and running line set in attic

Tags: hvac, mini-split

So the mini split I purchased calls for 3.5 inch hole to be cored from the handler unit to the outdoor compressor.

It’s always painful for me to see beautiful poured block walls destroyed, so my question revolves around whether I can avoid that, take the line set up through the attic and then back out of the soffit and then down the exterior wall to the compressor.

I wanted to know if the manufacturers have any reason for wanting it to go through the wall? The only logical thing I could think of is the drain line, but I will be handling that separately and it isn’t of a concern.

Is it just too many bends? You have a bend to get it up through the ceiling, then a bend to get it out of the soffit, or is it because ductless mini splits work best when the line sets stay lower than the handler?

So to sum it up, what are the pitfalls with going through the attic versus straight out a wall hole?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Refrigerant can only travel so far vertically before it needs special accommodation. Check the install manual for maximum refrigerant line length and rise. I hope your HVAC installer is competent and will know what is appropriate based on your specific unit.

---

> I wanted to know if the manufacturers have any reason for wanting it to go through the wall?

Besides the technical reason stated above I would say ease-of-install. Look at the unit physically and ask yourself "Does avoiding the hole in the wall complicate the mounting process or anything else?"

---

> It’s always painful for me to see beautiful poured block walls destroyed

So running copper lines along the entire exterior of your home is somehow more aesthetically appealing? Good luck when the time comes to redo your siding.

Comment: Got it. I mean the handler gets installed near the ceiling, so there’s linesets running on the wall regardless.